# Where to upload csr file for MDM.cer in iOS Provisioning Portal in Enterprise Account

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm

We recently got an Enterprise developer account from Apple. We are trying to setup MDM.

For that when i try to upload csr file for MDM, i didn't find the option Navigate to iOS Provisioning Portal  >  Certificates  >  Others  >  Request Certificate  >  Choose File

Is the option to upload csr file to generate mdm.cer has changed?

Can anyone help me where i have to upload csr file to get MDM.cer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Check this image.You can find the option

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It changed some time ago.

You need to go to [Apple identity portal](https://identity.apple.com/pushcert) and log in using your enterprise developer program.